Touching a buffer in C
I need to make sure that a memory buffer is all in physical memory and no page faults will occur when accessing it in a subsequent function, which cannot tolerate page faults due to some timing issues.  The buffer is allocated from the non-paged pool and often is composed of a lot of guard pages. A driver fills in the address space occupied by these guard pages with valid data when they are touched.
I came up with the following code to solve this problem:
#define PAGE_SIZE 4096
for (char* p = pbBuffer; (p < pbBuffer + cbBufferSize); *(volatile char*)p, p += PAGE_SIZE);
SubsequentFn(pBuffer, cbBufferSize); // Does not tolerate page faults.

This seems to work and the volatile keyword prevents the C compiler from optimizing away the "almost do nothing" for-loop.  See the compiled machine code below:
    000000013F3F1AA7 c7 c1 78 56 34 12    mov         rcx, pbBuffer
    000000013F3F1AAE 48 8D 91 00 00 10 00 lea         rdx,[rcx+cbBufferSize]  
    000000013F3F1AB6 48 3B CA             cmp         rcx,rdx  
    000000013F3F1AB9 73 14                jae         Main+4Fh (013F3F1ACFh)  
    000000013F3F1ABB 0F 1F 44 00 00       nop         dword ptr [rax+rax]  
    
    000000013F3F1AC0 0F B6 01             movzx       eax,byte ptr [rcx]  
    000000013F3F1AC3 48 81 C1 00 10 00 00 add         rcx,1000h  
    000000013F3F1ACA 48 3B CA             cmp         rcx,rdx  
    000000013F3F1ACD 72 F1                jb          Main+40h (013F3F1AC0h)  
    000000013F3F1ACF ...

As you can see the instruction movzx eax,byte ptr [rcx] touches the memory but the register eax is not used for anything else within the loop - which is the intended effect.
Q: Is this the best way trigger Guard Pages in the buffer or is there a better way ?  Will that code break in some circumstances ?

Yes, with GCC at least *p even without assigning it to anything counts as a "volatile access" to the pointed-to memory, for volatile char *p.  You might as well just make p volatile instead of casting every use, and that could be the loop body instead of part of a comma operator in the increment part of a for loop.  To get the compiler to touch memory, that's good choice.  The page size is definitely always going to be at least 4K or some multiple of that even on non-x86 ISAs.

@PeterCordes: When I made the p volatile then the machine code became very inefficient even with compile optimizations turned on.  The p is written and read from memory, every time it is being accessed ...even when the PAGE_SIZE is added to it.

I mis-spoke earlier; you don't want p to be volatile, you want it to be a pointer-to-volatile.  https://godbolt.org/z/8nM9KodGv shows GCC making the same asm for my touch_buffer_v2 as for your original.  And a version with char *volatile p that stores/reloads the pointer on every access like you're talking about.

@PeterCordes: Very nice. I'll accept this as the answer.

You cannot guarantee that the buffer will remain in physical memory without OS-level support - the OS can decide to page your buffer out anyway if it's experiencing memory pressure, even if it was recently accessed.
Instead, consider using an OS-specific API to lock the buffer into physical memory. On Linux (and many other POSIX systems, such as macOS and BSD), use mlock; on Windows, use VirtualLock. These functions will lock a specified region of memory, preventing it from being paged out.

If allocating with raw mmap, you can use Linux mmap(MAP_LOCKED) to save system calls.  You can use mlock on memory from malloc or C++ new, but you should munlock it before free.  (If the allocator hands it back to the OS, munmap will effectively munlock the region).

You mean besides never declaring any page file right?

The caveat is that I do not allocate the buffer (pbBuffer).  I am given this buffer by another function and this buffer is allocated by this function from a non-paged pool and has a lot of guard pages in it.  These quard pages must be triggered for the contents of the buffer to become valid... they just cannot be triggered inside the SubsequentFn().

@Joshua: That won't necessarily help; modern OSes can and do use compress pages into part of RAM, typically achieving 2:1 or 3:1 compression with lz4 or zstd.  If you disable that, too, then it would be unlikely for an OS to ever unmap the page-table entries for a dirty private page.  Usually an OS can just clear the "accessed" bit instead of fully unwiring it from the page tables, even if they just want to see if it's still hot.

@GeorgeRobinson: What do you mean by a "guard page"?  Normally that means an unmapped page (or actually mapped PROT_NONE) before or after pages you actually use, so touching one would SIGSEGV, invalid page fault.  But anyway, mlock on all pages that contain any data you're going to touch is like touching those pages yourself, even if that requires the OS to allocate them.  It's not limited to just locking already-hot pages.  (That would be really inconvenient since you'd always need a retry loop e.g. using mincore to find out which pages were evicted between touch and lock).

@PeterCordes: The guard pages are described in the link in my original questions.

@GeorgeRobinson when you say "nonpaged pool" - are you writing something in the Windows kernel? Nonpaged pool allocations are by definition in physical memory and won't fault. If by "guard page" you mean a page with PAGE_GUARD set, I believe you can just toggle that bit off with VirtualProtect.

@nneonneo:  Yes.  Also, I do not want to toggle that bit off with VirtualProtect, because if I do that then the the contents of the buffer will not become valid.  A driver fills in the address space occupied by these guard pages with valid data when they are touched.

I think that's context that you really should have had in your original question, then. And, in that case, what you've done is basically the best way to do it.

I added the stuff about the guard pages to the original question.
